# Bethe-Bloch Equation plotting incorrectly at high energies

Tags: particle-physics, computational-physics

Hopefully this is a quick fix, but I've been working on this for 3 days to no avail, so perhaps some external perspective will help.

Basically, I'm building a MatLab module to calculate mean particle $\frac{dE}{dx}$ from the Bethe-Bloch equation.  To verify that I'd implemented it correctly, I used the particle Data Group chapter on "Particle Interaction with matter" (see link at end for a pdf thereof).  Unfortunately, as you can see in the following plot, my implementation does not match the data very well at all.

[image]

The PDG data was digitized from the widely available plot seen below:

[image]

To generate the blue data series in the first plot, I merely calculated the following quantities for a range of (total) proton energies $E_n$ in MeV:

$$\gamma_n = \frac{E_n}{E_0}$$

where $E_0$ is the rest energy of the incident particle (proton) in MeV.

$$\beta_n = \sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{1}{\gamma_n}\bigg)^2}$$

$$p = \sqrt{E_n^2 - \bigg(\frac{E_0}{c^2}\bigg)^2} = \frac{E_0}{c^2} \beta \gamma$$

$$T_{max}=\cfrac{2 m_e c^2 \beta^2 \gamma^2}{1+\cfrac{2 \gamma m_e}{M}+\bigg(\cfrac{m_e}{M}\bigg)^2}$$

Where $p$ is the particle momentum, $M$ is the rest mass of the incident proton in g, $m_e$ is the rest mass of an electron in g,and $c$ is, of course, the speed of light in m/s.  I calculated the density effect, $\delta$ with the Sternheimer parameterization where:

$$x = \log{\beta \gamma}$$
$$
\delta(\beta \gamma) =
\begin{cases}
2(\ln 10)x -\bar{C}  & \text{if }x\geq x_1; \\
2(\ln 10)x -\bar{C}+a(x_1-x)^k  & \text{if }x_0\leq x < x_1; \\
0  &  \text{if }x<x_0\ \text{(nonconductors)};  \\
\delta_010^{2(x-x_0)}  & \text{if }x<x_0\ \text{(conductors)}; \\
\end{cases}
$$

Finally, the Bethe-Bloch equation I used (straight from the PDG pdf) was as follows:

$$-\frac{dE}{dx} = K z^2  \frac{Z_{target}}{A_{target}} \frac{1}{\beta^2} \bigg[\frac{1}{2} \ln\frac{2 m_e c^2 \beta^2 \gamma^2 Tmax}{I^2}-\beta^2 - \delta/2\bigg]$$

For lead, the following material parameters were used: $Z_{target} = 82$ amu, $A_{target}=207.2$ g/mol, $I= 823$ eV.  For the calculation of $\delta$, the following parameters were used (see link below for source): $C=6.2018$, $X_0=0.3776$, $X_1=3.8073$, $a=0.09359$, $k=3.1608$,and $\delta_0=0.14$.  $K$ was taken to be constant at a value of 0.307075 $\frac{MeV mol}{g}$.

Unfortunately I still get the error evident in the first plot where the Fermi Plateau doesn't seem to be in evidence.  Does anybody see anything wrong in the steps I took to calculate $\frac{dE}{dx}$?

For the record, this is NOT a problem with programming/MatLab, my trouble lies with the computation of $\frac{dE}{dx}$.  The issue is simply that the Bethe Bloch equation, when computed, does not appear to reflect the behavior seen in the PDG plot from literature.

PDG Link:
http://pdg.lbl.gov/2009/reviews/rpp2009-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf

Sternheimer Parameterization Link:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0092640X84900020

Comment: Have you open sourced your MATLAB module ? I'd to take a look at the source code so I can gain some insight into calculating $dE/dx$

Answer (score 2):

Murhphy's law.  Found out what was wrong as soon as I posted to the exchange.  my $I$ was in the wrong units (eV instead of MeV).